# How to populate database table from a file in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I'm working on small Android project in eclipse.  I created a database table but instead of populating the columns using EditText control, I want to populate it using data from a file (txt or xml).  I have a table shown below populated using EditText.

Database class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqldb) {
    myTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE staff"      +
            "(staff_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            "staff_Name TEXT,"               +
            "appointment_Day TEXT,"          +
            "start_Time TEXT,"               +
            "end_Time TEXT,"                 +
            "comment TEXT)";

    sqldb.execSQL(myTableQuery);
}

public void AddStaff(String id, String name, String day, String start, String end, String comment){

    SQLiteDatabase sqldb=this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("staff_ID", id);
    values.put("staff_Name", name);
    values.put("appointment_Day", day);
    values.put("start_Time", start);
    values.put("end_Time", end);
    values.put("comment", comment);

    sqldb.insert("staff", null, values);
    sqldb.close();


}
```

AddActivity class:

```
public void AddRowItemTable(View v){


    EditText staff_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sId);
    EditText staff_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sname);
    EditText day = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.day);
    EditText start = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.start);
    EditText end = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.end);
    EditText comment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment);

    String id = staff_id.getText().toString();
    String name = staff_name.getText().toString();
    String d = day.getText().toString();
    String s = start.getText().toString();
    String e = end.getText().toString();
    String c = comment.getText().toString();

    MainActivity.myDB.AddStaff(id, name, d, s, e, c);
    Intent newintent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(newintent);

}
```

Instead of doing it this way, how can I read data from file to populate it.  File looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<staff>

    <record staff_ID="S1" staff_Name="John" appointment_Day="Monday" start_Time="9" end_Time="12" comment="xxx"/>
    <record staff_ID="S2" staff_Name="Bob" appointment_Day="Monday" start_Time="10" end_Time="11" comment="xxx"/>

</staff>
```

Any help..??

Comment: And where did you have difficulties when you tried it? Reading the file, extracting the values, putting them into the database, ...

Comment: The difficult is that I don't know any way to read from the file.  I only know how to extract data from input (EditText).  Any hint..!!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you will have to parse your xml that you have placed in the assets folder and then put those values in db. You can try looking into parsing android xml in this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app/). A simple pull parse code would look something like this. Here `test.xml` is the file name that holds you xml in the assets folder.

```
        //File in assets folder
        InputStream tinstr = null;
        try {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            tinstr = assetManager.open("test.xml");
            parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(tinstr));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to parse your xml file, you can using XmlPullParser. For example, put your xml file (here is test.xml) in the assets folder.
and the xml file is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<staff>

    <record staff_ID="S1" staff_Name="John" appointment_Day="Monday" start_Time="9" end_Time="12" comment="xxx"/>
    <record staff_ID="S2" staff_Name="Bob" appointment_Day="Monday" start_Time="10" end_Time="11" comment="xxx"/>

</staff>

And the code to read the xml file is:

1. firstly, you can define a class to present the data, like 
public class Record{
        private String staff_id;
        private String staff_name;
        private String appointment_day;
        private int start_time;
        private int end_time;
        private String comment;
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.equals(o);
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.toString();
        }
        public String getStaff_id() {
            return staff_id;
        }
        public void setStaff_id(String staff_id) {
            this.staff_id = staff_id;
        }
        public String getStaff_name() {
            return staff_name;
        }
        public void setStaff_name(String staff_name) {
            this.staff_name = staff_name;
        }
        public String getAppointment_day() {
            return appointment_day;
        }
        public void setAppointment_day(String appointment_day) {
            this.appointment_day = appointment_day;
        }
        public int getStart_time() {
            return start_time;
        }
        public void setStart_time(int start_time) {
            this.start_time = start_time;
        }
        public int getEnd_time() {
            return end_time;
        }
        public void setEnd_time(int end_time) {
            this.end_time = end_time;
        }
        public String getComment() {
            return comment;
        }
        public void setComment(String comment) {
            this.comment = comment;
        }

    }
2. In the place where you want to read the file, define
private List<Record> lists = new ArrayList<Record>();
this lists contains the record, here in this test file, there are two records to read

3. The cord to read the file:

// File in assets folder
        InputStream tinstr = null;
        XmlPullParserFactory factory;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            tinstr = assetManager.open("test.xml");
            parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(tinstr));
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            Record record = null;
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String xmlName = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(xmlName.endsWith("record")){
                        record = new Record();
                        record.setStart_time(Integer.valueOf(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "start_Time")));
                        record.setAppointment_day(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "appointment_Day"));
                        record.setComment(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "comment"));
                        record.setEnd_time(Integer.valueOf(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "end_Time")));
                        record.setStaff_id(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "staff_ID"));
                        record.setStaff_name(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "staff_Name"));
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if(xmlName.endsWith("record") && record != null){
                        lists.add(record);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope this can help.